# Does the Single Sign On Paradigm respects the HTTP protocol rules?

Tags: java, http, https, single-sign-on, cas

We are using the CAS server for a JAVA web application.
 The authentication system is as follows:

- A user tries to access a resource (1) on the system
- It get redirects (**302 Found**)
- The User Enters the username password
- The Server answers with a cookie and redirects to the original page (1)

I am debated on the fact that this interaction respects the HTTP protocol.

If I do not have the authorization to access a resource
shouldn't the system answer with a **401 Unauthorized** or even better a **407 Proxy Authentication Required**  ?

And the Authorization Resource, couldn't be instead of a Cookie string a full SSL-Level authorization key ?

**Added:**
Header dump using curl -L -D

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 02:07:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://server.com/service/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 02:07:55 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=q7rjikj4spvd1fxaowjl9XXX
Location: https://server.com/login/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 02:07:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Content-Length: 6650
```

Comment: I'm curious, what HTTP Status is returned by the page you are sent to after the 302 Found (with the prompt for the username password)?  Could it have a 401 Unauthorized status?  (I don't think 407 would be appropriate, as it's not really a proxy.)  A capture of the HTTP Headers (using Live HTTP Headers in Firefox, for example) would be really nice to have here, regardless.

Comment: Proxy I think is intended as "Another Service" instead of the typical http proxy service.  I added the Http headers. And is even worse that want I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - the SSO system in your examples is really at a different level than the HTTP protocol itself.  If the application returned a 401 then the browser itself will likely handle the authentication (e.g.: prompt the user for username/password, then send the next request with this base-64 encoded in the HTTP Authorization header).  In the case of HTTP Basic authentication the username & password would then be sent with every request to your system.  You may do authentication with Kerberos or NTLM, in which case the authentication could be transparent if the user is already logged into the network.

That said - many SSO systems take the approach of redirecting the user to a login HTML form, and then maintaining session state with a cookie.  One of the main benefits is you have more control over the look & feel of the login interface.  With the SSO system having a session cookie it can take ownership of maintaining the state in its own (likely proprietary) way.